# Installing Linux headers on Kali

Tags: linux, virtualbox, kali-linux

I recently installed Kali on Virtual Box and when I try to install the Linux-headers by using the code

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y linux-headers - $(uname -r)
```

it reads the following error

```
E: Package 'linux-headers' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package 5.7.0-kali1-amd64
E: Couldn't find any package by glob '5.7.0-kali1-amd64'
```

I tried re-installing both Virtual Box and Kali but still got the same result. I tried a few fixes that were available on the internet but they all returned errors. Please help.

Comment: Kernel for newest Kali is 5.8.0.  Do you need to upgrade the Kernel first?  Here is an article on upgrading Kali Kernel.   https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/get-linux-kernel-5-3-on-debian-10-stable/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but installing Kali in Parallel tools for macOS, maybe will help you.
By default, the LiveCD of Kali bring the version linux-headers-5.9.0-kali1-amd64, and when you try to install the headers you get the error unable to locate.

The problem is solved if the kernel is updated using:

```
sudo apt install linux-image-5.9.0-kali5-amd64
sudo apt install linux-headers-5.9.0-kali5-amd64
```

In the future if these packages are not available, you can always check which is the latest using:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt search linux-headers
```